# What does 嫩主 mean?

Tags: meaning

There's this sentence in *The Dark Forest* by Liu Cixin:

> “你看看，刚才你主动提这事儿，现在又说自己可能杀她，咱就是随便聊聊，你急着抖落这些干吗？一看就是个嫩主。”

Joel Martinsen translated the sentence like this:

> “Look at you, bringing up the issue on your own. Saying you may have killed her, even. We’re just having a casual chat. What’s your hurry? You’re new at this, that much is clear.”

That gives the impression that 嫩主 means something like: greenhorn/novice/newbie/rookie.

Most of the results online for "个嫩主" only bring up the same quote from *The Dark Forest*, but there are a few others:

- 新来的主儿太嫩，总要TMD给这些个嫩主儿找点个杈儿。
- 一看212楼就是个嫩主，你还生活在鼓里，别看一下CCAV就乱下评论，
- 也不能说他那天都是装的，只是聊着聊着他就发现Helen绝不是个嫩主儿，表现的不卑不亢

It doesn't seem that greenhorn/novice/newbie/rookie can necessarily be directly substituted for 嫩主 here, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think your impression is correct.

Comment: Maybe some other alternatives: naïve, inexperienced, innocent…

Comment: newbie. Why do you not find a English edition as a reference. Indeed English version is not good enough as the first season.

Comment: I just realize, my last comment maybe made misunderstanding. It means "newbie"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your impression is correct, it can also be expressed as

> 生瓜蛋子
>
> 生手
>
> 新手

I will keep adding when I recall more of those.